# How can I conditionally add values to my pivot table from a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to update the values fields of pivot tables based upon the names of the fields. For example, I have Fields named "add me", "add me too", "add me also", and "column1", "column2", and "column3". I essentially need to loop through these fields, and add "add me", "add me too", and "add me also", but ignore "column1", "column2" and "column3".

I've been trying to do this by assigning a range within the sheet, looping through, and dependent upon value, trying to add them as values.

```
Sub check_data_columns()

Dim c As Range
Dim pvt As PivotTable

For Each c In Range("data_input_columns")

    If Left(c, 6) <> "Column" Then
        Debug.Print "OK column:" & c.Value
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivot_by_week").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivot_by_week").PivotFields(c), "sum of " & c, xlSum

    Else
        Debug.Print "nothing in column: " & c.Value
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

I'm getting error 1004 every time.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: The error is here: `PivotFields(c)`. `c` is defined as a range. `PivotFields()` expects a string. Use `PivotFields(c.Value2)` instead.

Comment: This fixed it - thanks! Annoyed I missed something so obvious (now).

Comment: happens from time-to-time, even after 15 years of programming!

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is that your Named Range `Range("data_input_columns")`, has more than just a header row, but also rows with data below it.

Therefore, when you loop `For Each c In Range("data_input_columns")` and you reach the  2nd row with data, you are getting an error.

I use `For Each C In Range("data_input_columns").Rows(1).Cells` to loop through the first row only, where most likely you keep your header row, and these are the values you want to compare with `<> "Column"`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub check_data_columns()

Dim C As Range
Dim pvt As PivotTable

' set the Pivot Table, will have a shorter cleaner code
' avoid using ActiveSheet, try to use fully qualified object, such as Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivot_by_week")

For Each C In Range("data_input_columns").Rows(1).Cells ' loop through first row (header row)
    If Not UCase(C.Value) Like "COLUMN*" Then '<-- just in case you have small or capital letters
        Debug.Print "OK column:" & C.Value
        pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields(C.Value), "sum of " & C.Value, xlSum
    Else
        Debug.Print "nothing in column: " & C.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but Scott Holzman's answer was what I needed. Again - thanks!